# Laravel - find info in db using request parameter

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am building a API using laravel, and i am trying to create a function to find a user in data base using a email as a parameter

```
public function find_user(Request $request){
    try{
        $user = UserAccess::table('user_accesses')->where('email', $request->email)->first();
        return ['api_request_return'=>'ok', 'return' => $user];

    }catch(\Exception $error){
        return ['api_request_return' => 'error', 'error_details' => $error];
    }
}
```

The API route is ok, but its always returning error:

```
{
     "api_request_return": "error",
     "error_details": {}
}
```

Comment: Please try to use DB::table('user_accesses')->where('email', $request->email)->first();

Comment: Because you are using DB and Eloquent together. Kindly use one.

Comment: Or, go with the model way i.e. `UserAccess::where('email', $request->email)->first();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the corrected one

```
public function find_user(Request $request){
    try{
        $user = DB::table('user_accesses')->where('email', $request->email)->first();
        return ['api_request_return'=>'ok', 'return' => $user];

    }catch(\Exception $error){
        return ['api_request_return' => 'error', 'error_details' => $error];
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try to use DB::table, its warning "Undefined type 'DB'.intelephense(1009)"

Comment: from IDE https://ibb.co/Rzv0TW0, but when i make request, is returning null value: {
    "api_request_return": "ok",
    "return": null
}

Comment: Check whether user_accesses table have the given email record in database. 
Its return null when not found

Comment: This is the table: https://ibb.co/q0H2SNY and GET request: https://ibb.co/P5qqMZ4

Comment: Please dd the value $request->email ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> die(print_r($request->email)) and check whether variable has value in it

Comment: Code: $user = DB::table('user_accesses')->where('email', $request->email->die(print_r($request->email)))->first();  Return: Error: Call to a member function die() on null in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/beemanager-api/app/Http/Controllers/Api/UserAccessController.php on line 55

Comment: Not like that.. just add line of code die(print_r($request->email)) before try block

Comment: Sorry, i change the route in api.php and it works, for some reason the application was unable to get a request